# SSO possible with LDAP-backed web applications?

Tags: http, authentication, web-applications, ldap, single-sign-on

I have a client who wants their wordpress and google apps user accounts accessible using SSO, ie if they log in on one app domain google.client.com they will be logged into wordpress.client.com too without extra steps.

The same LDAP directory will be used to do backend authentication for both systems.  Is it possible to setup SSO for LDAP-backed webapps?

Comment: I'm aware of how both Google apps and Wordpress handle ldap - but how would the ldap credentials get passed from a desktop terminal onto either's website (assuming the user steps are: log in to the desktop, fires up either google.client.com or wordpress.client.com in their default webbrowser?)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Open Id to achieve SSO. Google Apps and Wordpress both integrate well with openid.

Comment: how would I link up openid to the ldap server that the user would use to log in against at their wintel desktop?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Google Apps supports SAML to address SSO integration with LDAP authentication. You can get more information on a simple SAML IdP solution from www.pingidentity.com.

Comment: how does PingIdentity pass the desktop login details to the webbrowser and webapps?